# Are Braid Groups with Finitely many Generators NIP?

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory

I am curious what braid groups (strings in $\mathbb{R}^3$) are [NIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NIP_(model_theory)). Consider the following:

Let $B_\mathbb{N}$ be braid group with "braids" indexed by the natural numbers (alternatively, the direct limit of braid groups on finitely many braids with inclusion maps between them). This structure (in the language of groups) is not NIP.

**Proof:** There is a formula which shatters arbitrarily large (finite) subsets of $B_\mathbb{N}$. Consider the formula $\varphi(x;y) \equiv xy \neq yx$

Let $\{\sigma_i : i \in \mathbb{N}\}$ generate $B_\mathbb{N}$. Let $A_n = \{\sigma_0, \sigma_3,...,\sigma_{3m},..., \sigma_{3n}\}$. Let $I \subseteq A_n$. Suppose that $I = \{\sigma_{j_1},...,\sigma_{j_k}\}$. Then, let $b_I = \sigma_{j_1 +1} \circ ... \circ \sigma_{j_k +1}$. If $I = \emptyset$, let $I = \sigma_t$ where $t>3n+1$.   Then, we have that $$B_\mathbb{N}\models \varphi(x, b_I)\iff \sigma_j\in I;\forall \sigma \in A_n $$

Since we can shatter arbitrarily large finite sets $\implies$ $B_{\mathbb{N}}$ is not NIP.

$\boxdot$

**Remarks:** The proof that $B_{\mathbb{N}}$ is not NIP relies on the fact that there are infinitely many generators. While I find this interesting, it is not helpful in understanding whether braid groups with finitely many generators are NIP. I am curious to know whether $B_n$ is NIP for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Futhermore, I should remark that $B_1,B_2$ are NIP since $B_1$ is finite and $B_2 \cong \mathbb{Z}$ (in the group language) and since $\mathbb{Z}$ is stable, $B_2$ is NIP. But, more specifically, I am asking the following question:

**Question:** Is $B_3$ NIP?

Comment: To make your question more self-contained, you could include a definition (or link to a definition) of NIP.

Comment: Nice question. Do you know that this group is not stable? In any case, a proof that $B_3$ is NIP, would imply that $PSL(2,\mathbb Z)$ is NIP and that is not known (this latter group is most probably stable). If it is true, I expect it to be very difficult to prove.

Comment: @MarkGrant: Sure thing. I have added a link to the definition.

Comment: @KyleGannon: Thanks! Now I can see that I'm out of my depth here and move on :)